# Flutter navigation stacking

Tags: dart, flutter

I wonder how I would be able to achieve the routing between two screens with the ability to go back to the previous one but without stacking them all.

Currently, I have two routes: `/` and `/planets` default initial route is `/` and when I navigate to the `/planets` I get the stack of two routes and I am able to go back to the `/` and then exit the app. But also with that when I click multiple times both routes they're stacking over each other and I get infinite route stack. I would like to get max stack size of 2 and navigate through this with the ability to pop(). Is it possible ? How I can achieve this?

```
void _navigateTo(BuildContext context, Screen screen) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    if (Screen.HomeScreen == screen) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
    } else if (Screen.PlanetsScreen == screen) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/planets');
    }
  }
```

this is resulting with the stack of size 1 and always when I push and want go back app closes..

Comment: Why do you redirect to `/` from `/planets` instead of just poping the route ?

Comment: I have a drawer that navigates from screen to screen

Comment: basically, you want to pop from `/planets` back to `/` and from `/` push to `/planets` Pop will remove the route from the stack

Answer (score 0):

The `Navigator` class in flutter provide a solution for this problem.

You can use `pushReplacementNamed` and `popAndPushNamed` method.

`pushReplacementNamed` execute with enter animation.

`popAndPushNamed` execute with exit animation.

good lock :)